# First-Review Queue: Always Show Question

Tags: feature-request, review, new-users

I have started looking at the "first answers" review queue, and I find that I almost always need to see the question (and, often, other answers) in order to gain context.  Other than link-only and other obvious issues, it is very difficult to know if an answer is "good" if we don't know what is being asked.

I know that the question is available in another tab, but I think it would be helpful to be able to see the question and answer at the same time.  Personally, I think that it should be the default view, along the same lines as the "Suggested Edit" queue.

Comment: I don't agree. Sometimes we can clearly know if it need more explaination or not. For me it's good now

Comment: @Elikill58 - yes, I agree that *sometimes* we can tell right away.  The more I dig into it, though, the more I'm convinced that *more often* it's easier to tell with more context.  If we don't need that extra context but have it, it can be ignored.

Just my opinion.